# Ron Paul's brain count

Tags: riddle, wordplay, rhyme, knowledge

> The number of brains found inside Ron Paul's head.
>   With playing or model; it rhymes with small bread.
>   A half of the seats of one-seven-two filled.
>   With character, lead, voice; between screen and guild.
>   In best-of-three, rounds that one needs for a win.
>   A breathing gas followed by claw marks on skin.

Who am I?

Hint:

> Looking for the name of a fictional character.

Comment: Does the "best-of-three" refer to the (rot13)orfg zbivr va n gevybtl?

Comment: This one has completely stumped me

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think the answer is

> THE GODFATHER or, if you prefer, VITO CORLEONE.

The number of brains found inside Ron Paul's head.

> ONE, unless this is a most regrettable intrusion of politics into PSE. Or maybe "brains" here can mean hemispheres, in which case there are twice as many?!

With playing or model; it rhymes with small bread.

> ROLE (which rhymes with ROLL).

A half of the seats of one-seven-two filled.

> Dunno. Just SIXTY-SIX? I haven't found any super-plausible thing for "one-seven-two" to be a reference to. (Planes, cars, trains, all possible.) [EDITED to add:] Most likely, as suggested by Eutherpy, is that 172 means the Cessna 172 light aircraft, in which case the number would be TWO -- which, see below, is certainly the number we want.

With character, lead, voice; between screen and guild.

> ACTOR or perhaps ACTORS.

In best-of-three, rounds that one needs for a win.

> TWO.

A breathing gas followed by claw marks on skin.

> Notable breathing gases are air, oxygen, nitrox, heliox, hydrox, hydreliox, neox, trimix, heliair. Claw marks on skin: scratches, welts. No combination of these seems much use to me, with or without replacements like nitrox -> NO. [EDITED to add:] Shahriar Mahmud Sajid found what is clearly the right answer, namely O+SCARS -> OSCARS.

Putting these together we get

> ONE ROLE TWO ACTORS TWO OSCARS.

Therefore the character is

> THE GODFATHER or VITO CORLEONE, for playing whom both Marlon Brando and Robert De Niro won Oscars. Lots of other roles have had multiple Oscar *nominations* for different actors, but I think this is the only one with two actual Oscar awards.

Credit where it's due:

> Shahriar Mahmud Sajid got OSCAR(S), which I consider the trickiest thing here. Eutherpy got two TWOs, one of which I had had independently and the other of which I had multiple options for. Go upvote both of their answers if you like mine.

Comment: The Cessna 172 holds four people, so half of that would be 2. Also, half of 172 would be eighty six, not sixty six

Comment: @Tom I'm sorry, but I don't think I understand either of your suggestions.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan - I deleted my comments - but still think there's more intrigue to the number of brains.

Comment: Still no explanation for why Ron Paul - By the logic given, it could've been literally any human, or for that matter quite a lot of non-humans.  Politics aside, was the name chosen just as click-bait?

Comment: @DarrellHoffman Just needed a two-syllable name. I thought about using rot13[Wnpx Oynpx] or even rot13[Oenaqb], but didn't want to point directly into the correct topic area. (Also, rot13["fbzrbar"] contains the answer directly.) The reason I like RP here is that it doesn't give away anything, and it might even send people in the wrong direction initially since you wouldn't think the obvious answer can be correct when the clue is that specific.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman plus, you know, clickbait :)

Comment: @jafe Okay, nothing wrong with that.  I was just thinking maybe it was related to a recent speech he gave or something.  You know, something along the lines of *"As sure as I've got a brain in my head, I know you should all [support/oppose] this [bill/candidate]"* or whatever...

Answer (score 12):

**Partial:**

A breathing gas followed by claw marks on skin.

> this could be Oscar, O for oxygen- breathing gas, scar for claw marks on skin.

Answer (score 9):

I think the answer might be something related to

> two

A half of the seats of one-seven-two filled.

> half of four seats in a 172 Cessna

In best-of-three, rounds that one needs for a win.

> you need 2 out of 3 in order to win a "best-of-three"

But I don't have anything else :D Working on it!

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer is:

> Vito Corleone

The reasoning is:

> 1 
>  Role (rhymes with small bread) 
>  2 actors 
>  2 (best 2 out of 3) 
>  Oscars (Oxygen (O) + claw marks (Scars))

There is only one instance I can think of where

> two actors each won an Oscar for playing the same character.

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE! Thank you for your answer, we're glad to have your contribution! As a quick tip, please feel free to check out other answers before posting your own - I believe @Gareth McCaughan has already posted a similar answer for this question. Happy puzzling!! :)